# When to use Push-Location versus Set-Location?

Tags: powershell, directory-structure

At first sight [Set-Location](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849850.aspx) and [Push-Location](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849855.aspx) PowerShell cmdlets look alike when it comes to changing the current directory.

What are use cases for each? When would one choose to use one over the other?

Comment: push-location acts like a sort of stack of path, you can then use pop-location to revert to a previous saved path. The doc : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849855.aspx

Comment: Why would someone use Set-Location then, if Push-Location gives you the same functionality with extra stack of paths feature? :)

Comment: because you may not want go back to a previous dir, and I think set-location will consume less ressource

Comment: Fair enough, yet resource consumption sounds like a lousy enough reason to have both. I feel it still deserves a nice SO answer.

Comment: I think it's only a convenience and a legacy of the cd, pushd command of cmd.exe ...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They will both change the working directory but using `Push-Location` will add the current working directory to the top of a stack before changing to the new working directory. You can then use `Pop-Location` to traverse back down the stack through the previous working directories.

`Set-Location` will just change the working directory in the same way that `cd` would.

```
Set-Location = cd
Push-Location = pushd
Pop-Location = popd
```

Comment: One problem is that `Push-Location` does not change `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory` in the console host, but does in the ISE host. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56462392/447901