# Current directory apparently not current directory

Tags: powershell

Running this code in ISE works.

```
Push-Location -Path $(Split-Path -Parent $myInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
Get-Location
$file = '.\ex.txt'
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($file)
```

Running the same code in Console fails. What am I missing?

```
PS H:\src\powershell> .\ccount.ps1

Path
----
H:\src\powershell
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Could not find file
'C:\src\powershell\ex.txt'."
At H:\src\powershell\ccount.ps1:9 char:11
+ $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($file)
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands
   .NewObjectCommand
```

**How this is different from the suggested duplicate**

The other question/answer does give an explanation for why PowerShell fails in this case. However, it does not give any hint as to why this works in ISE. This seems to be a significant difference between the Console and ISE host.

I am running PSVersion 5.0.10586.117 on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't .NET objects in PowerShell use the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246068/why-dont-net-objects-in-powershell-use-the-current-directory)

Answer (score 1):

```
Push-Location -Path $(Split-Path -Parent $myInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
$myInvocation.MyCommand.Path
Get-Location
$file = Resolve-Path '.\ex.txt'
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($file)
```

Comment: This is exactly what does not work in the Console host. Were you running this in ISE?

Comment: I was running this on both ISE and console host. My environment is windows 10 though. Check `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory`  environment variable. It might be set differently in console host and ISE

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
Push-Location $PSScriptRoot
```

It will work in both cases as long as you're using a recent PowerShell version (v3+).

Comment: This is incorrect, the issue is not with `$myInvocation.MyCommand.Path` but with creating a .Net object with `New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($file)`. As the asker shows, the location returned by `Get-Location` : `H:\src\powershell` does not match the location in the error message `'C:\src\powershell\ex.txt'`

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be that `Push-Location` does not change [Environment]::CurrentDirectory in the console host. It does change it in ISE.

```
PS 09:02 \\SRV1\SH1\home\pwatson2 H:\
>Push-Location H:\src\t

PS 09:02 \\SRV1\SH1\home\pwatson2 H:\src\t
>Get-Location

Path
----
H:\src\t

PS 09:02 \\SRV1\SH1\home\pwatson2 H:\src\t

>Write-Host ([Environment]::CurrentDirectory)
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```